# Retrieve item by path in a branch different than default master in Azure DevOps repository using GitHttpClient

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the `GitHttpClient` in **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi** package to interact with repository hosted in Azure DevOps. I am wondering if there's a way in the API to retrieve an item by path in a different branch than the default `master` branch, because I don't find a parameter in the method `GetItemAsync` (or similar API methods) under `GitHttpClient` that supports branch.

I also tried to change the DefaultBranch to the branch I want to retrieve the item from, but the `GetItemAsync` still retrieves the item from the default `master` branch.

```
repo.DefaultBranch = "my_intended_branch"; // does not change the behavior of GetItemAsync
```

Anyone knows how to retrieve a GitItem from a branch different than the default master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitversiondescriptor?view=azure-devops-dotnet)

Basically what I need to do is to create a GitVersionDescriptor object with the branch name, and pass the object to the method `GetItemAsync()`, it works.